# Errors using tensorflow-lite on Visual Studio

Tags: tensorflow, visual-c++, tensorflow-lite

I am new to C++ and I tried to do a project using a tflite model on Windows, but can't seem to build it on Visual Studio 2019.

I built tflite 2.2.0 following [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows), with bazel 2.0.0, with the following commands :

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so //tensorflow:install_headers //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
```

I then added includes and libraries to my project's properties, and my inputs look like this:

```
libtensorflow_cc.so
libtensorflow.so
libtensorflowlite.so
```

But when I run my project, i get the following :

```
Erreur  LNK1107 fichier non valide ou endommagé : impossible de lire à 0x2F8    personmask  B:\tensorflow\tensorflow-2.2.0\bazel-bin\tensorflow\lite\libtensorflowlite.so   1
```

PS : I also tried to build tensorflow with VS2017 with

```
bazel build -c opt --config=v2 //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
```

but only got `FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully` with one of two more explicit errors a few hundred lines before the fail, depending on wether I use `--config=v2` on the build command :

```
ERROR: B:/tensorflow/tensorflow-2.2.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:799:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_contraction_kernel_with_mkl' failed (Exit 2)
ERROR: B:/tensorflow/tensorflow-2.2.0/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/BUILD:688:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu:runtime_single_threaded_matmul' failed (Exit 2)
```

Would you have an idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: Does Visual Studio use .so files on windows builds? I think you need to build tensorflow using Visual Studio 2019 and not some other compiler.

Comment: I thought. A C++ dev gave me that part.. Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Looks like mingw or linux instructions that you are trying.